# Dynamic programming without using the recursion?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Usually, I have seen that problems that are solved using the dynamic programming end up using the recursion which is understandable due to its property. But would it be correct to say that Dynamic programming solution will for sure involve the recursion? Is it possible to have a dynamic programming solution that doesn't involve recursion and can be done in a linear way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

short answer is yes dynamic programming can be done linear way. Understand it as a optimization technique where you avoid recalculating the same value again. Lets understand it by a simple fibonacci example:

```
int getFib(int n){
 int fib[] = new int[n];
 fib[0] = 0;
 fib[1] = 1;
 for(int i=2;i<n;i++){
    fib[i] = fib[i-1]+fib[i-2];
  }
return fib[n-1];
}
```

now this is a classic dynamic programming example. its categorized as dynamic programming because here we are optimizing the calculation based on the previous calculation. This is true that lot of recursive algorithms are also dynamic programming problem but dynamic programming can also be linear as you can see in this example.